# Why is string.append(character) failing to compile, with the error "cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String' "?

Tags: swift, string

I am currently trying encode a string. Certain characters can be copied exactly as they are, while others must be percent encoded (this is for a URL). As part of this, I am looping over the input string and checking each character individually. If the character can be used as is, I simply want to concatenate the character to the output string as is. The string.append(character) function is producing a compiler error "cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String' ". I don't understand why this is happening.

I have tried using append with a literal character, and the same error gets produced. My code is as below:

```swift
var encoded: String = ""
for character in input {
    print("character: \(character)")
    if (character.isASCII) {
        if (Reserved.contains(character)) {
            encoded += encode(character)
        } else if (UnReserved.contains(character)) {
            encoded = encoded.append(character)
        } else {
            //TODO: Something
        }
    } else {
        encoded += encode(character)
    }
}
```

Comment: You even got it right two lines before that. Just do `encoded += character`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Just figured it out, although I noticed that as well @Sweeper, although it wouldn't cause a compiler error. Turns out that the function doesn't even return a string, but that it appends the character to the existing string. My head was too into the way languages that treat strings as immutable handle it.

Comment: By the way, if you want to do percentage encoding, you can just do `encoded = input.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the problem:

`encoded = encoded.append(character)`

You're appending the character to the `encoded` String variable. `append` returns Void (also known as `()`), and you're attempting to assign that void value to a String variable. Just append the character, no need to reassign the variable:

`encoded.append(character)`

Comment: I noticed this right after posting. Was forgetting that strings are mutable in swift, despite treating them as mutable the line before.